# Need help combining a CSS and HTML together

Tags: css, eclipse, html

I have to codes and I need help putting them together.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="loader">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.loader {
    text-align: center;    
}
.loader span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: loader 0.9s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: loader 0.9s infinite alternate;
}
.loader span:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.loader span:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes loader {
    0% {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        opacity: 0.9;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }  
    100% {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        opacity: 0.1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-21px);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes loader {
    0% {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        opacity: 0.9;
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        opacity: 0.1;
        -moz-transform: translateY(-21px);
    }
}
```

I need help combining so I can have an animation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use eclipse? You can use

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

in your index.html file, and then create a style.css file for the css.

There are 3 ways to style your html:

1. Inline ex: `<p style="color:red;">blah</p>`
2. Internal style in the `<head></head>` of your html file between `<style></style>` tags
3. External in a separate style.css file. Use the top example to attached external stylesheet

Comment: Wait but will it animate the item i want to use

Comment: @user3053057 of the 3 options I've outlined above, how are your files organized right now?